# What happens when using scanf("%d", &c) while c is a char?

Tags: c, types

the code is like this:

```
char c;  
scanf("%d", &c);
```

inputting 3...

My guess is that when `3` is inputted, it is as type `int`;
and then type-demoted to char and assigned to `c`;

I print the value of `c` in specifier `%d` yielding 3, seems to be as expected;
but printing the value of `c` with specifier `%c` yields --a blank-- on the terminal;this is one question...(1);
to test more I furthermore declare a variable `ch` with type `char` and initialized it like this:

```
char ch = 1;
```

and the test is like this:

```
(i&j)? printf("yes") : printf("no");
```

and the result is "no"
I print out the value of `i&j`, and it is `0`
but `1&3` should be `1`? this is another question....(2);
my question is (1) and (2)

Answer (score 4):

You're actually invoking undefined behavior doing that.

By using the format string `%d`, you're telling `scanf` to expect an `int*` as a parameter and you're passing it a pointer to a single character.  Remember that `scanf` has no further type information on what you're passing it than what you're putting in the format string.

This will result in `scanf` attempting to write an `int` sized value to memory at an address that points to a `char` sized reservation, potentially (and for most architectures) writing out of bounds.

After invoking UB, all bets are off on your further calculations.

Comment: so no type pro/demotion happens but is overwritting?

Comment: and say it is the case; but does whether my system is big/little endian matter? when will the overwritting happens like overwrite the 1-byte with the least byte of the 4-byte integer? and if so, ch(1)&c(3) should be 1?

Comment: @J.C. Yes, it will just mercilessly overwrite memory at that address, there is no type adaptation of any kind happening. Logically, I'd say you should see the value `3` in your char on a little endian machine, but the result of UB is rather clear, once you've done it, you can't rely on anything working in a predictable manner anymore.

Comment: I'd love to give you a vote, but I can't because of this: "Assuming a 32-bit integer, it will write the result as 4 bytes..." Suppose you were to mention that printf might attempt to write an `int` value into the space that's large enough to store a `char` value and that this might result in writing out of bounds of the `char` variable. This makes sense without mentioning numbers. An assertion that 32-bit integers are 4 bytes is misinformation, however. Consider `CHAR_BIT == 32 && sizeof (int) == 1`.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue You're right, removed the size assumptions in the answer since they only muddled things up. They were remains from a "memory dump example" I wrote at first but decided to remove since it got too long-winded.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that scanf() were not a varargs-function, but a plain ordinary function taking a pointer-to-int as the 2nd argument:

```
int noscanf(char *format, int *ptr)
{
  *ptr = 42;
  return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
  char ch;
  int rc;

      // This should *at least* give a warning ...
  rc = noscanf("Haha!" , &ch); 

  return 0;
}
```

Now, scanf() **is** a varargs function. The only way for scanf() to determine the type of the (pointer) arguments is by inspecting the format string. And a %d means : the next argument is supposed to be a pointer to int. So scanf can happily write `sizeof(int)` bytes to *ptr.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a variable `j`there. So `i&j` will be 0. And yes, if `i == 1` and `j == 3` then `i & j == 1`.

Comment: sorry, the j in my question is ch declared above...just typo

Answer (score 0):

(i&j)? printf("yes") : printf("no");
statement gives the output yes,for i=1 and j=3.

And for (1) question ASCII 3 is for STX char which is not printable.